# Which tense is correct? (Things in the past)

Tags: past-tense

Which one is correct?

- I wouldn’t have thought that a few years ago.

OR

- I wouldn’t think that a few years ago.

Comment: The correct one is the first one: > "I wouldn't **have thought** that a few years ago."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct in their own context:

"I wouldn’t have thought that a few years ago" either suggests some condition in the past--e.g. If you had suggested the context, *I would have provided* a more expanded answer--or it is equal to just "it's not likely that I thought that" or "I'm not the one to have thought that".

In "I wouldn’t think that a few years ago", *wouldn't* shows the refusal to think that in the past.

Answer (score 0):

'I wouldn't think' can be determined as past or conditional.

Here are two examples to illustrate my point:

1. 'When he was little, he used to go to the movies every day, and he would always see the same kinds of movies.' -- in this example, 'would' is being used to communicate the past, and in this case, it indicates that the action was habitual.
2. 'If I were rich, I would buy a big house.' -- We clearly see in this example that 'would' is being used in a conditional sense.

'I wouldn't have thought that a few years ago' is PAST conditional as Rompey has explained, and 'I wouldn't think that a few years ago' is indicating that the action was habitual in the past (as in the first example I provided), which I can emphasize by expanding the sentence:
'I wouldn't think that, at any point in time, really not once, and I would get lots of opportunities to think that, but I wouldn't ever allow myself to think that, I really wouldn't think that.'